# Calling a function with optional parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script which uses a required parameter and some optional. What would be the best way to call a function with these optional parameters?

Right now I have these `if`, but I'm pretty sure there must be a better way to handle this situation. Otherwise, what would I do if instead of 4 optional parameters they are 100 (bad practice, just for the example)? Use an `if` for each one?

```
def get_data(table, db='postgres', host='localhost', user='postgres', password=''):
....
....
....

kwargs = {}
if args.db:
    kwargs['db'] = args.db
if args.host:
    kwargs['host'] = args.host
if args.user:
    kwargs['user'] = args.user
if args.password:
    kwargs['password'] = args.password


data = get_data(args.table, **kwargs)
```

Comment: All those `if`s are doing is convert `args` to `kwargs`. Can't this be done with `**args`…?

Comment: @deceze args is the output of `argparse` `parse_args()`. If I try to use it directly it says `argument after ** must be a mapping, not Namespace`.

Comment: Use `get_data(**vars(args))`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey that's not right, unless OP specifies the same defaults in the argument parser as in `get_data`. OP doesn't want to override the function defaults.

Comment: @AlexHall True I guess, but I interpreted the question as "what's a smarter way to turn the `args` object into a dict", and for that `vars` is absolutely sufficient. Filtering out `None` values afterwards is easy enough. I've added a relevant dupe, and here's a piece of code for the lazy: `get_data(**{k:v for k,v in vars(args).items() if v is not None})`

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in 'db host user password'.split():
    val = getattr(args, key)
    if val:
        kwargs[key] = val
```